# binary tree traversal in c++

Tags: c++, netbeans-7, binary-search-tree

> i solved the solution by myself, please check it my code 'friends'.
>
> i have done a few changes in my code.
>
> check my program, i got the output when i debug the code in netbeans IDE of my laptop...
>
> the changes are done in my function calls and i build my constructor.

```
  #include <iostream>
1.#include <cstdlib>
2.#include <stdio.h>
3
4.using namespace std;
5
6.class binaryTreeTraversal
7.{
8.public:
9.int TreeNodes[2^5];
10.int size;
   int number;
   int depth;
11.binaryTreeTraversal(void);
12.bool LeafNode(int node);
13.int RootNode(int node);
14.int LeftPtr(int node);
15.int RightPtr(int node);
16.
17.int length();
18.int preOrderTraversal(int);
19.int inOrderTraversal(int);
20.int postOrderTraversal(int);
21.};  

//build the constructor
binaryTreeTraversal::binaryTreeTraversal():size(sizeof(TreeNodes)/sizeof(int)),number(0),depth(0)
{
for(int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
{
    TreeNodes[i] = -1;
}
}
22.bool binaryTreeTraversal::LeafNode(int node)
23.{
24.return LeftPtr(node) == -1 && RightPtr(node) == -1;
25.}
26.int binaryTreeTraversal::RootNode(int node)
27.{

29.root = (node-1)/2;

34.return (root >= size || TreeNodes[root] == -1)? -1 : root;
35.}
36.int binaryTreeTraversal::LeftPtr(int node)
37.{

39.left = (node-1)*2-1;

44.return (root >= size || TreeNodes[root] == -1)? -1 : root;
45.} 
46.int binaryTreeTraversal::RightPtr(int node)
47.{

49.right = (node-1)*2;

54.return (root >= size || TreeNodes[root] == -1)? -1 : root;
55.}
56.int binaryTreeTraversal::preOrderTraversal(int node)
57.{
58.if(node == -1)
59.{
60.    return (-1);
61.    cout<<"The Tree Nodes are:"<<node<<" = "<<TreeNodes[node]<<' ';
63.}
64.preOrderTraversal(LeftPtr(node));
65.preOrderTraversal(RightPtr(node));
66.}
67.int binaryTreeTraversal::inOrderTraversal(int node)
68.{
69.if(node == -1)
70.{
71.    return (-1);
72.    inOrderTraversal(LeftPtr(node));
73.}
74.cout<<"The Tree Nodes are:"<<node<<" = "<<TreeNodes[node]<<' ';
75.inOrderTraversal(RightPtr(node));
76.}
77.int binaryTreeTraversal::postOrderTraversal(int node)
78.{
79.if(node == -1)
80.{
81.    return (-1);
82.    postOrderTraversal(LeftPtr(node));
83.}
84.postOrderTraversal(RightPtr(node));
85.cout<<"The Tree Nodes are:"<<node<<" = "<<TreeNodes[node]<<' ';
86.}
87.int binaryTreeTraversal::length()
88.{
89.return depth;
90.}
91.int main(int argc, char** argv) 
92.{
93.binaryTreeTraversal btt;
94.btt.size = 13;
95.btt.TreeNodes[0] = 27;
96.btt.TreeNodes[1] = 12;
97.btt.TreeNodes[2] = 3;
98.btt.TreeNodes[3] = 8;
99.btt.TreeNodes[4] = 43;
100.btt.TreeNodes[5] = 9;
101.btt.TreeNodes[6] = 7;
102.btt.TreeNodes[7] = 61;
103.btt.TreeNodes[8] = 38;
104.btt.TreeNodes[9] = 65;
105.btt.TreeNodes[10] = 99;
106.btt.TreeNodes[11] = 77;
107.btt.TreeNodes[12] = 22;
108.cout<<"The Left-ChildNode of 9 is: \n\n"<<btt.LeftPtr(9)<<' ';
109.cout<<"The node 12 is LeafNode: \n\n"<<btt.LeafNode(12)<<' ';
110.cout<<"The node 6 is LeafNode: \n\n"<<btt.LeafNode(6)<<' ';
111.cout<<"The RootNode of 10 is: \n\n"<<btt.RootNode(10)<<' ';
112.cout<<"The preOrderTraversal values are: \n\n"<<btt.preOrderTraversal(0)<<' ';
113.cout<<"The inOrderTraversal values are: \n\n"<<btt.inOrderTraversal(0)<<' ';
114.cout<<"The postOrderTraversal values are: \n\n"<<btt.postOrderTraversal(0)<<' ';
115.return (0);
116.}
```

Comment: `#include <iostream.h>`. `stdio` does not provide `cin` and `cout`. The compiler did tell you it can't find `cout`... a momentary glance at documentation for same should tell you what headers declare it.

Comment: yes, but i think its just iostream not iostream.h

Comment: If you're going to paste such a huge slab of code with compiler errors, it would be helpful to at least include line numbers too – are we supposed to count where line "115" is?

Comment: @zmccord, #include<iostream> works but i am receiving an error, saying that: 

main.cpp:32: error: expected primary-expression before "int"
main.cpp:32: error: expected primary-expression before "int"

but when i use #include<iostream.h>, it works and i am getting an error free code, but unable to build successful.

Comment: I don't think the problem has anything to do with binary tree traversal. Consider changing the question.

Comment: @visanio_learner: Will all your question be full quotations now? Did you not ask yourself why it is (prolly) different coloured than other people's questions?

Comment: @visanio_learner: Also, your line numbers are not synchronous to the error messages... and, INDENT PROPERLY ...

Comment: yeah that error i mentioned was on my netbeans IDE, here the problem is on line number 24.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what the line 31 report is about but when I compile your code, the error is reported on line 24 which is invalid. Line 24 is:

```
return (binaryTreeTraversal::LeftPtr(int node) == NULL && binaryTreeTraversal::RightPtr(int node) == NULL);
```

and I suspect you mean for it to be:

```
return (binaryTreeTraversal::LeftPtr(node) == 0 && binaryTreeTraversal::RightPtr(node) == 0);
```

The line 61 error is because you've included `stdio.h` instead of `iostream`

You titled your question "binary tree traversal in c"... do you truly believe your question has anything at all to do with that?

Comment: yeah you're right, it was line 24 here, but it was in my netbeans IDE, that i said, sorry

Comment: i used #include<iostream.h>
and everything is clear, error free code, but i am unable to build my code successfully, its failing to build

Comment: actual problem is: i am unable to build the program.

Comment: Unable to build due to new problems, or the same ones? I've addressed both problems you pasted in your question; you've solved the iostreams issue but you didn't indicate seeing the other solution I pasted. Note: I'm able to compile your code correctly when applying both of these changes though it doesn't link. It fails to link because you failed to provide a constructor for the binaryTreeTraversal class, though you declared that one exists when you defined the class.

Comment: yeah i did both the include directory as well as the 'error: expression before int' "binaryTreeTraversal::LeftPtr(node)==0" but it shows a warning: NULL used in arithmetic, when i remove and build it.

Comment: If you're still getting the NULL warning -- its because you didn't fully replace the existing code line. Your original code compared an int to NULL, causing that warning. My replacement included replacing both NULL's with 0.

Comment: thank you for your reply, i have solved it from some reference thro' net, now check my output is correct or not...